# Quantum Mechanics: Spin states along different axes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-states

I was reading Quantum Mechanics: The theoretical minimum by Leonard Susskind.
It says that we can describe spin states along x, y and z axes in terms of orthogonal vectors U and D. If we assume that U and D are orthogonal vectors describing the spin states along z-axis, shouldn't the spin states we derived along the y-axis and those along the x-axis be similar as both are symmetric with respect to the z-axis?

Comment: What do you mean by similar?

Comment: I mean we should be able to interchange them without affecting anything else.

Comment: They are similar indeed. They just differ by a factor of i multiplicating the down state. The imaginary unit acts basically as a 1, it doesn’t affect probabilities. They have the same symmetry properties.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!